# Test automation within a waterfall project. What to consider?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework, waterfall

**Details:**

In my new project I am to set up an automation, waterfall based project for a client. Since I have completed test automation exclusively within Agile projects so far, and in Waterfall rather relied on manual testing, for me a very new experience.

So far from planning, there are several thousand manual test, which I can certainly automate for regression testing to a large extent. However, I am still asking myself some questions that I have not been able to fully clarify even with research.

**Questions:**

- Other than regression testing, what else can be automated within a
  waterfall project?
- What do I need to look out for that might just be completely
  different to agile test automation?

Comment: I would suggest to re-phrase your question to be more context-driven. "Agile project" and "Waterfall project" may mean 1000 different things and, thus, your testing strategy cannot be well-structured without more specific information. In this light, I would suggest highlight what is your business context, testing goals, resources, people/skills, (and additionally) processes.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends**

For the most part, the nature of the software will govern the kind of automation that you can use. The development methodology is, in my experience, secondary - the main difference I've seen between working agile and working waterfall is that everyone tends to work with smaller slices of functionality in an agile environment where a waterfall environment tends to deliver anything from a module to a complete application in one big chunk.

That said, in your position I'd be looking at specification documents as soon as you have access to them. These will help you to decide what areas of the project are best suited for regression automation, where you might want to focus for any load or stress testing, and even whether you want to build a setup automation suite.

The biggest difference the methodology makes in my opinion is that there's a tendency to hand a supposedly complete piece of code over for testing in a waterfall environment, which can make testing - and consequently automation - challenging because fixes usually take longer to be implemented and you may need some interesting workarounds. There could also be less testability built into the software (this isn't a given, but I've found it's more likely to happen in a waterfall environment than in an agile environment).

Other than that, you're likely to have a  more or less hard deadline to work against, which will mean that any delays you encounter will mean less time for other things.

As long as you work with the nature of the software you're testing, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can, automate the design and API tests as well, when automating in the waterfall project.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the community. This is a pretty sparse answer that doesn't really answer the question. Can you add more details? How have you gone about testing in a waterfall project? Can you provide more concrete examples?

Comment: Yea actually, generally in waterfall its a separate testing phase which is only kind of manual testing. But since you asked a question regarding the automation, I think when working in waterfall project, you can do design or automate the designs when you are in the design phase. So for the APIs when in Implementation phase.